# Sqoop hive incremental Loading

Tags: hive, sqoop

I have a sqoop job which is executing fine for many days. Due to some issue One instance of Job is failed and from next instance, I am receiving below error. I even tried creating new Job and nothing works and moreover append mode doesn't work with the hive.

**Error during import**:

`--merge-key or --append is required when using --incremental last modified and the output directory exists`

hive version : `0.14`
sqoop version :`1.4.6`
hadoop version : `2.7.1`

Comment: This post may help you. http://www.technoligent.com/articles/sqoop-incremental-load-failed-without-job.html. It suggests creating a new job with `-- merge-key <column>` as part of its definition.

Comment: Thanks Jagrut for your suggestion but same was running fine initially without this --merge-key option